# Create config directory in linux with Rust

Tags: linux, rust, directory, config, create-directory

Started learning rust yesterday so im a complete newbie. I wanted to make a command line program for linux as my first project. I want it so when you run the program it checks if the config directory `~/.config/my_program/config.toml` exists. If it does it loads the settings from the toml file (which I will probably make another post for), but if it doesn't exist it instead creates it and puts the default settings in the toml.

Here is what I have so far:

```rust
use toml;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let config_path = "~/.config/my_program/config.toml";
    
    //checks if the director exists
    let config_exists = Path::new(config_path).exists();
    println!("{}", config_exists);

    if !config_exists {
        let default_config = "place_holder";
        match std::fs::create_dir_all("~/.config/my_program"){ //If it doesn't exist it creates the directory
            Err(error) => panic!("Couldn't create config directory: {}", error),
            Ok(file) => file,
        };
        let mut config = match std::fs::File::create(config_path){ //Creates the file itself
            Err(error) => panic!("couldn't create config file: {}", error),
            Ok(file) => file,
        };
        match config.write_all(default_config.as_bytes()){ //Writes the default config to the file
            Err(error) => panic!("Couldn't write defualt config to file: {}", error),
            Ok(_) => println!("Config file created at: {}\nEdit it in order to change some setings.", config_path),
        };

    } 
    
}
```

But nothing seems to work nicely with `~` referencing the home directory.

Basically what I need here is to get the user who is running the program and just pass in the full directory: `"/home/user/.config/my_program/config.toml"`.

I have tried it with `users::get_current_username().unwrap()` but that returns an 0sString which can't easily be combined with normal &str and passed in as arguments.

So either learn how to turn an 0sString in to a &str or just try a completely new approach.

Comment: `~` is interpreted and substituted by the **shell**, you cannot use it directly in a low-level file API (whatever the language). Try [`to_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.to_str) or [`to_string_lossy()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.to_string_lossy).

Comment: The dirs crate has cross-platform directories like [`config_dir`](https://docs.rs/dirs/latest/dirs/fn.config_dir.html). Also `~` is the same as the `$HOME` environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example in order to illustrate the idea.
It just deals with a simple text file (no specific format).

Many of the involved system calls may fail (no such file, permission denied...) thus we have to propagate the errors with [`?`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator).

[`PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#) is dedicated to multiple path operations; it is very convenient here.
We try to keep using [`OsString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html)/[`OsStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html) as much as possible for path manipulations because nothing guaranties that the underlying file-system/OS conforms to the utf-8 `String`/`str` Rust uses internally.

```rust
type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>;

fn load_config(
    user_relative_path: &str
) -> Result<(std::ffi::OsString, String)> {
    let home_dir = std::env::var_os("HOME").ok_or("no home directory")?;
    let mut config_path = std::path::PathBuf::new();
    config_path.push(home_dir);
    config_path.push(user_relative_path);
    let config_content = if let Ok(content) = std::fs::read(&config_path) {
        String::from_utf8_lossy(&content).to_string()
    } else {
        "This is the default content\n".to_owned()
    };
    Ok((config_path.into_os_string(), config_content))
}

fn save_config(
    config_path: &std::ffi::OsStr,
    config_content: &str,
) -> Result<()> {
    let dir_name = std::path::Path::new(&config_path)
        .parent()
        .ok_or("incorrect directory")?;
    std::fs::create_dir_all(dir_name)?;
    std::fs::write(&config_path, config_content)?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let (config_path, mut config_content) =
        load_config("config_test_dir/config.txt")?;

    config_content += &format!(
        "{} chars before, but here is something new.\n",
        config_content.len()
    );

    save_config(&config_path, &config_content)?;

    println!("config file saved to {:?}", config_path);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: After looking at this I can comfortably say I underestimated how hard this might be. I will first have to learn a lot more in order to understand what's happening here so my project is going to wait a bit. Thanks!